# Lag with CALayer when double tap on the home button

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, lag

When I put shadow etc. with CALayer my app is lagging when I double tap on the home button to see tasks running. I don't have any other lag, just when I double tap.

I call this method 20 times to put 20 images :

```
- (UIView *)createImage:(CGFloat)posX posY:(CGFloat)posY imgName:(NSString *)imgName
{   
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
    sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, 65, 65);
    sublayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    sublayer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    sublayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = sublayer.bounds;
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    imageLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:imgName].CGImage;
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [sublayer addSublayer:imageLayer];

    [myView.layer addSublayer:sublayer];

    return myView;
}
```

I have commented all my code except this, so I'm sure the lag comes from here. Also I've checked with the Allocations tools and my app never exceeded 1Mo. When I'm just putting images without shadow etc. everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `shadowPath` on the layer as well. It will need to be a rounded rect since you've got rounded corners on your layer.

CALayer has to calculate where it is drawing, and where to put the shadow, if it doesn't have a shadow path. This has a big effect on animation performance.

Another way to improve performance with CALayers is to set the `shouldRasterize` property to YES. This stores the layer contents as a bitmap and prevents it having to re-render everything.

Comment: I tried to add this :
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:sublayer.bounds];
    sublayer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;

But it doesn't change anything. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: No, that's what I meant. Sorry it doesn't help. Is there a reason you're using two layers added to a view's existing layer instead of, say, creating a UIImageView and changing the properties of its layer? That would probably have better performance.

Comment: No reason at all, I just followed a tutorial. I'm gonna try with an UIImageView and tell you back. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok I remember why. Cause when I work with UIImageView, I have a bug with cornerRadius. I have white rect part all around my radius corner. I can join a screenshot if you doesn't understand what I mean. So I made a "container" all around my image to have a proper radius. Whatever, I tried with an UIImageView (I have the corner radius bug) and when I commented this line : imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0; my program doesn't lag anymore. So the lag doesn't come frome shadow but from my weird bug. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm sure it's the complexity of the layers. Try shouldRasterize, see edited answer.

Comment: Yeah I already tried it but my images looks bad and still lagging but less than shouldRasterize set to NO

Comment: I'm running out of ideas then. Is the image a different size to the view you are putting it in? Have you profiles using the time profiler in instruments?

Comment: My images are larger than the view. And for time profiler, I never used it. And again, thanks for your time.